# How to call solidity function in html 'inspect' console properly?

Tags: web3js, remix, abi

I can see my contract in my console. The solidity code and abi is in the the index.html. I can't figure out how to call this function and send 0.01 ether with it as well. I would think it is something like GuessingGame.playGame(function() {}) but where could I possible see where it wants it's parameters? I can get it to work in remix by doing compile > create > input .01 ether in value > hit playGame button

https://github.com/whvod/DoubleorNothing

Comment: Unrelated, but your contract is probably not doing what you want. In the current setting, everyone wins all the time, since you use msg.value to determinate if the user wins, and you're forcing it to be a certain value (0.01 ether). Plus in what i assume is an attempt to generate a random number, you're using blockhash(block.number) which always returns 0. Use blockhash(block.number - 1) instead, or prevrandao if you're on ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

Using [web3.js v1+](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/), you have to:

1. get the contract instance: `const ctr = new web3.eth.Contract(abiDefinition, ctrAddress)`
2. [`send()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-send) a transaction to the contract method:

   `const txId = await ctr.methods.playGame().send({from: sendingAccount, value: amountInWei })`